# Shiro LDAP Authorization config

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, vaadin, shiro

Could you please help me with the following situation?

**Background information:**

- I'm using the [Vaadin framework](https://vaadin.com/home).
- I'm using the [Java security framework Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)
- I'm using ssl.
- Authentication works.
- Username syntax = pietj@.lcl , jank@.lcl
- memberOf field is being used as role.
- shiro.ini

> [main]

```
contextFactory = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory 
contextFactory.url = ldaps://<SERVER>:636 
contextFactory.systemUsername = <USERNAME>@<COMPANY>
contextFactory.systemPassword = <PASSWORD>
contextFactory.environment[java.naming.security.protocol] = ssl 

realm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm 
realm.ldapContextFactory = $contextFactory 
realm.searchBase = "OU=<APPDIR>,DC=<COMPANY>,DC=lcl" 
realm.groupRolesMap = "CN=<ROLE>,OU=<APPDIR>,DC=<COMPANY>,DC=lcl":"Admin"
```

> [roles]

```
 # 'Admin' role has permissions * 
 Admin = *
```

**Goal**

- Authorization mapping based on the memberOf field from the currentUser.

**Problem**

- currentUser.hasRole("Admin") always return false.

**Questions**

- Is the above shiro.ini correct?
- How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue using Shiro 1.2.4. Your Shiro configuration is probably OK and the problem lies in ActiveDirectory configuration.

In my setup some users had the **userPrincipalName** attribute set, while other users hadn't. You can check your in AD server with [Sysinternals Active Directory Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx) for example.
This attribute is the one used by Shiro to search for a particular user, then it looks for groups defined in the **memberOf** attribute.
Take a look at [ActiveDirectoryRealm.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/activedirectory/ActiveDirectoryRealm.java) source code, method `Set<String> getRoleNamesForUser(String username, LdapContext ldapContext)` the exact query used is
`String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=*)(userPrincipalName={0}))";`

So you have two solutions:

- Set **userPrincipalName** attribute on every user
- Change how Shiro searches for users

I went for the second solution. Changing the search query is harder than it should be: you have to customize `queryForAuthorizationInfo` and `getRoleNamesForUser` (because its private) methods of `ActiveDirectoryRealm` class. This is how I did it:

```
public class CustomActiveDirectoryRealm extends ActiveDirectoryRealm {

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo queryForAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals, LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {
        String username = (String) getAvailablePrincipal(principals);

        // Perform context search
        LdapContext ldapContext = ldapContextFactory.getSystemLdapContext();

        Set<String> roleNames = null;

        try {
            roleNames = getRoleNamesForUser(username, ldapContext);

        } finally {
            LdapUtils.closeContext(ldapContext);
        }

        return buildAuthorizationInfo(roleNames);
    }

    // Customize your search query here
    private static final String USER_SEARCH_FILTER = "(&(objectClass=*)(sn={0}))";
    private Set<String> getRoleNamesForUser(String username, LdapContext ldapContext) throws NamingException {
        Set<String> roleNames;
        roleNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String userPrincipalName = username.replace("acegas\\", "");
        if (principalSuffix != null) {
            userPrincipalName += principalSuffix;
        }

        Object[] searchArguments = new Object[]{userPrincipalName};

        NamingEnumeration answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, USER_SEARCH_FILTER, searchArguments, searchCtls);

        while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();

            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

            if (attrs != null) {
                NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll();
                while (ae.hasMore()) {
                    Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();

                    if (attr.getID().equals("memberOf")) {

                        Collection<String> groupNames = LdapUtils.getAllAttributeValues(attr);

                        Collection<String> rolesForGroups = getRoleNamesForGroups(groupNames);
                        roleNames.addAll(rolesForGroups);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return roleNames;
    }
}
```

And then of course use this class as Realm in shiro.ini

```
[main]
realm = your.package.CustomActiveDirectoryRealm
realm.ldapContextFactory = $contextFactory 
realm.searchBase = "OU=<APPDIR>,DC=<COMPANY>,DC=lcl" 
realm.groupRolesMap = "CN=<ROLE>,OU=<APPDIR>,DC=<COMPANY>,DC=lcl":"Admin"
```